# open a div by clicking over an image in whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a hamburger icon in my page and by clicking over it, it opens a div right below it. These hamburger icons are multiple in my page.

As you see below my code, I want to open the `class="pop"` below the hamburger icons as I click on them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#openDrop").click(function() {
     //to be implemented
  });
});
```

```css
.pop {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #999;
  height: 125px;
  width: 80px;
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="pop">
  <br/>
  
    <div>Mark
      <br/>
      <br/>ReshaD
      <br/>
      <br/>Thomas
      <br/>
    </div>
  
  <br/>
</div>

<img id="openDrop1" src="http://s24.postimg.org/yalcvye1t/hamburger.png" style="position: relative; left: 170px; top:-70px;  cursor: pointer;">

<img id="openDrop2" src="http://s24.postimg.org/yalcvye1t/hamburger.png" style="position: relative; left: 300px; top:-70px; cursor: pointer;">
```

Is there any solution in order to do so?
thanks in advance.

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07nfsx07/8/)

Comment: `<center>` - Which century are you in? This is outdated and not supposed to be used.

Comment: Side note, [don't use the `<center>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: And also, can you update the jsfiddle inside the snippet? Coz 100s of devs don't have the access to it?

Comment: Also, you have duplicate ID's..

Comment: **Duplicate IDs** - That's one main issue.

Comment: I will update it now.

Comment: @reshad Awesome... `:)`

Comment: @JFit duplicated id's also changed :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar edited as you suggested

Comment: Your jQuery is looking for `openDrop` but your IDs are `openDrop1` and `openDrop2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed up your fiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/07nfsx07/9/

bascially you can perfect it yourself but heres the general gist of what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".openDrops").click(function(){
       x = $(this).offset().top + 20 + 'px';
       y =$(this).offset().left + 20 + 'px';
       $('.pop').css('top', x).css('left', y).show();
    });
});
```

Also changed your CSS a little:

```
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
```

and your HTML

```
<img id="openDrop1" class="openDrops" src="http://s24.postimg.org/yalcvye1t/hamburger.png" style="position: relative; left: 170px; cursor: pointer;">

<img id="openDrop2" class="openDrops" src="http://s24.postimg.org/yalcvye1t/hamburger.png" style="position: relative; left: 300px; cursor: pointer;">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :)